# Engine Size and Fuel Consumption (cost of driving Audi TTS)

Tags: engine, fuel-system, fuel-consumption

My boyfriend drives an Audi TTS 08 and recently has told me that it costs £15 just for 22 miles in petrol to see me, that's why I apparently don't see him much. When I confronted him about it, he said it costs him that much as his car has a bigger engine.

Is this true or is he lying? Taking into consideration the car model and its engine size?

I know it may sound like a stupid question, but I have no clue when it comes to cars…

Comment: My only thought is, if he has money enough to own that car, he has money enough to drive down the road 22 miles to see his sweetie. I'd tell him he should trade the car in for a new, more fuel efficient model, or you'll trade him in on a new one ... just my 2 cents worth and only comment worthy.

Comment: Get a new boyfriend, he is equating your value as a girlfriend to MPG of his vehicle, he sucks big time, send me your phone #, I will not do that ever!

Comment: Methinks he's prevaricating. But, that said, the cost of operating a car is more than just the fuel, so *perhaps* he's trying to say that £15 is the total cost  (fuel, insurance, maintenance, etc.) of the trip. Still, it might be worth considering a trade in…

Comment: I have 3 vehicles: 1970 Charger, 1989 Suburban, and a 2000 4x4 Ford van with a 7.3l diesel. They all use more fuel than any Audi. I would have driven any of these fuel guzzling monsters wherever and whenever my girlfriend asked. I'm married to her now and I would still do it. Bottom line: **Dump the loser.**

Comment: damned straight lads....dump the cheap loser

Comment: @plainclothes: I suspect you have forgotten the Audi R8, but your point is well taken.  After writing the previous sentence I see the V10 Plus still rates 14 mpg city, 22 mpg highway so you are probably right after all.

Comment: @RossMillikan if he was driving an R8, we'd already know he was jerk. A TTS is the lesser jerk's car. And yes, even the R8 could best two out of three of my cars.

Answer (score 6):

According to a [Google Search](https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=audi%20tt%202008%20fuel%20consumption), his car should get 23 MPG city, which would cost about £3.82 for a one way trip (average £1.01/litre).

To figure this out for any car, first do a search to figure out what the mileage is. Just search for the year/make/model of the car. This should easily get you the figures.

Next, figure out how far the trip is, in your case it's 22 miles, which is just about the same as what the car would go for one gallon of gas, or 3.8ish litres of fuel. I also did a search to figure out how much the average litre of fuel costs in the UK (assuming you are in the UK since you used £ symbol in your question). Then just multiply out the amount of fuel used by the amount it costs for said fuel and there you go. Easy-peasy math.

Hope this helps you either get your BF to put up or shut up, and maybe you'll be seeing him a little more often or move on to the better model.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was right...but unfortunately he's still  insisting that it does cost more in fuel...

Comment: @K.M - Sounds like it's time for option #2 then, and trade him in for the new model.

Answer (score 4):

If your boyfriend can afford a  Audi TTS. He should be able to afford the fuel to visit his lady as often as she would like. I don't think this a mechanical issue. Therefore model of vehicle and size of engine  is irrelevant I think the issue is more with boyfriend than the Audi TTS. I think a trade-in is order.... FYI I ain't referring to the car.

I notice by other comments...the other gentlemen echo the same sentiments.

Comment: He can afford the car, just not the girlfriend......

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was right...but unfortunately he's still  insisting that it does cost more in fuel...

Comment: @k.m- Your boyfriend has a warped sense of priorities. Any other guy I am sure would not care about the cost of fuel. He wouldn't make excuses. As we say here "the hell with the expense throw the cat another canary."

Answer (score 1):

As a direct answer to the question, generally yes, the larger the engine the more fuel they use.

When the engine is cold, it will use more fuel and stop start traffic will also increase fuel consumption for a given distance.

That said, many engines and the TTS, are turbo charged and therefore use more fuel than their size would suggest. An example is in motorsports where a turbocharged engine has its capacity multipled by 1.4 to get an equivalent size.

One more factor is that engines are turned for economy or performance. The latter will sacrifice fuel efficiency for power, and that is also the case with the TTS.

Finally, to echo the other answers, no it'll not cost £15 quid to do 20 miles, unless you're pouring it out of the tank at the same time.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was right...but unfortunately he's still  insisting that it does cost more in fuel...

Comment: It will cost more in fuel than is he had a normal TT, or a diesel one, or a 1 litre city car, so there's a grain of truth in what he is saying. The numbers are exaggerated for sure, and fundamentally either you can afford to run a car or not... The servicing, tyres, parts and everything else will also cost more. If what he's saying is true then the car is beyond his means... Champagne lifestyle on beer money!